# How to use Replace function in Sql Server using Regex

Tags: sql-server

**Problem Statement:**

I have more than 1 million records that have long html text data in the description column of a table. I want to replace Html tags from the text using the REPLACE function available in SQL Server.

**Example:**

```
<div style='width:100%;height:500px;'> 
            Some text here <span style='color:red;'> sample text </span>
            <img src='[image url here]' alt='test image' />
           </div>
```

**Expected Output:** Some text here sample text

**Solutions Tried:** I have founded one function that removes all the html tags from text and returns the plain text. But that method is taking very long as it iterates through each html tag in the provided text and stuff it.

So I am thinking to use REPLACE function with Regex to replace all html tags at once by blank.

I have seen many examples of REPLACE function with regex, but none working for me.

The approach that I am thinking is like:

```
DECLARE @HtmlText NVARCHAR(MAX) = `<div style='width:100%;height:500px;'>
```

Some text here  
sample text `

```
SELECT REPLACE(@HtmlText, '<%>', '')
```

From above query I want it will find html tags like: `<div style='width:100%;height:500px;'>` and replace it with blank.
Similarly for other html tags also.

Please help me with right regex that I can use in my REPLACE.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: SQL Server does not support regex, it supports very basic pattern matching with syntax that is very similar to regex. What is the function you are using? Maybe we can help make it faster.

Comment: When you say you tried some examples of REPLACE with Regex, but they didn't work, can you please provide an example of what you tried and what was wrong with the result?   As Sean says, there is no Regex in TSQL, but maybe you're using the CLR?  Your question isn't clear on this point.

Comment: Sql server is just not the right tool for this job. It's better to do in a programming language, not in t-sql.

Comment: I tried this query which is similar to like statement in SQL: SELECT REPLACE(@HtmlText, '<%>', '');   so in this query regex part is:  '<%>', where % is to include all text that startes with '<' and ends with '>'

Comment: @VaibhavAgrawal you can't use regular expressions in SQL Server. In fact, you can't use regular expressions to parse HTML. If you want to sanizite HTML input or remove formatting you should use a client-size library to do this. With jQuery it could be as simple as `jQuery("<p>Hi there</p>...").text();`. In C# you could use HTML Agility Pack to parse the input data and extract the text only